# What is the relation between countability and recursive enumeration?

Tags: uncountability

Does recursive enumeration implies countability?
Does countability implies recursive enumeration?

I believe the first implication holds but not sure about the second. A good  example would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a language is recursively enumerable then it is countable. However, there are languages that are countable but not recursively enumerable. For example, consider the $A_{TM}$, the language of the Halting problem. This language is recursively enumerable while its complement $\Sigma^*-A_{TM}$ is not recursively enumerable, otherwise $A_{TM}$ would be decidable. However, $\Sigma^*-A_{TM}$ is clearly countable since it is a subset of a countable set $\Sigma^*$.

Hence one simple relation between countability and enumeration is that every r.e. set is countable, but the opposite is not always true.

Comment: sir first of all thanks for your awesome answer..I have a small query that -: "if a language is Recursive enumerable then it may be infinitely uncountable " ?

Comment: @laura First of all the word "infinitely" in "infinitely uncountable" is redundant. If a set is uncountable it is already infinite since any finite set is countable.  Second, if a language is recursively enumerable then it is countable. As its name "enumerable" implies this set can be enumerated, i.e., put in one to one correspondence with a set of a natural numbers, and hence countable.

Comment: sir can we conclude that any language is a subset of  $\sum ^ {*}$ and as  $\sum ^ {*}$ is countable so a **non Recrsive enumerable** is countable too ?

Comment: @laura Assuming that $\Sigma$ is finite, **any** subset (language) of $\Sigma^*$ is countable. It is also countable even when $\Sigma$ is *infinitely countable*.